# How to change date format while exporting as a csv file?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I use below code and its working fine. I don't want to change temp table field(dActiveDate) type but please help me to change the date format.

Note - Date format can be changed by user. It can be YY/MM/DD or DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YY and so on...

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt_data NO-UNDO
   FIELD cName AS CHARACTER
   FIELD dActiveDate  AS DATE.

   CREATE tt_data.
   ASSIGN
     tt_data.cName = "David"
     dActiveDate     = TODAY
     .
   OUTPUT TO value("C:\Users\ast\Documents\QRF\data.csv").
   PUT  UNFORMATTED "Name,Activedate" SKIP.
   FOR EACH tt_data NO-LOCK:
     EXPORT DELIMITER ","  tt_data. /* There are more than 15 fields available so using export delimeter helps to have less lines of code*/ 
   END.
   OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

Answer (score 1):

As this a "part two" of this question: [How to change date format based on variable initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65032245/how-to-change-date-format-based-on-variable-initial-value) why not build on the answer there?

Wrap the dateformat part in a function/procedure/method and call it in the `EXPORT` statement. The only change required will be to specify each field rather than just the temp-table.

```
 EXPORT DELIMITER ","  
    dateformat(tt_data.dactivedate, cDateFormat)
    tt_data.cName
```

This assumes that there's a function called dateformat that takes the date and format and returns a string with the formatted date (as in the previous question).

Comment: Good logic and It works fine if I export it as txt file but date format is not changing if i export it as csv file

Comment: @Thiru That might depend on Excel (if its where you open the file).

Answer (score 0):

"and so on..." needs to be specified. Depending on the specification you may have to resort to a custom function like Jensd's answer.

If you can constrain the formats allowed, you can use normal handling by using:

```
session:date-format = "ymd" / "mdy" / "dmy". 
session:year-offset = 1 / 1950. // for four vs two digit year
```

How you populate these two variables can be done in similar fashion as in the other question.

You may need to reset these session attributes to their initial state in a finally block.